# How to parse Inner-XML return from SharePoint Web Services

Tags: c#, .net, xml, sharepoint

I have a program as such

```
    // establish proxy obj
    SPLists.Lists listservice = new SPLists.Lists();

    // credentials
    listservice.PreAuthenticate = true;


    // user name
    Console.Write("Username (e.g. bobdole@xyz.com): ");
    string usrname = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
    Console.Write("\n");

    // pw
    Console.Write("Password: ");
    string password = MaskedConsoleReader.ReadLine();

    // auth
    listservice.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(usrname, password);

    // List Service URL
    listservice.Url =
      "https://wss.xyz.com/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";

    // Instantiate an XmlDocument object 
    System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();


    /* Assign values to the string parameters of the GetListItems method, 
    using GUIDs for the listName and viewName variables. For listName, 
    using the list display name will also work, but using the list GUID 
    is recommended. For viewName, only the view GUID can be used. 
    Using an empty string for viewName causes the default view to be used.*/
    // Work ticket list
    // {5B79ED7D-ECB7-447A-9331-22984E52EB7D}
    // All tickets view
    // {00F95DDD-C383-4E4A-94F2-977FDA7A7F74}

    string listName = "{5B79ED7D-ECB7-447A-9331-22984E52EB7D}";
    string viewName = "{00F95DDD-C383-4E4A-94F2-977FDA7A7F74}";
    string rowLimit = "4000";

    /*Use the CreateElement method of the document object to create 
    elements for the parameters that use XML.*/
    System.Xml.XmlElement query = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Query");
    System.Xml.XmlElement viewFields =
        xmlDoc.CreateElement("ViewFields");
    System.Xml.XmlElement queryOptions =
        xmlDoc.CreateElement("QueryOptions");

    /*To specify values for the parameter elements (optional), assign 
    CAML fragments to the InnerXml property of each element.*/
    query.InnerXml = "<Where><Gt><FieldRef Name=\"ID\" />" +
        "<Value Type=\"Counter\">3</Value></Gt></Where>";
    viewFields.InnerXml = "<FieldRef Name=\"Title\" />";
    queryOptions.InnerXml = "";

    /* Declare an XmlNode object and initialize it with the XML response 
    from the GetListItems method. The last parameter specifies the GUID 
    of the Web site containing the list. Setting it to null causes the 
    Web site specified by the Url property to be used.*/

    DateTime abc = DateTime.Now;
    string format = "yyyy-M-dd_HH-MM-ss";
    string xyz = abc.ToString(format);
    string fName = "dump-" + xyz + ".txt";

    try
    {

        System.Xml.XmlNode nodeListItems =
            listservice.GetListItems
            (listName, viewName, query, viewFields, rowLimit, queryOptions, null);

        StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter(fName);


        /*Loop through each node in the XML response and display each item.*/
        foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode listItem in nodeListItems)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(listItem.OuterXml + "\n");
            outfile.WriteLine(listItem.OuterXml);

        }
        outfile.Close();


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ERROR!: " + ex.ToString());
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\n");
    Console.WriteLine("Contents dumped to: " + fName);

    // hold program
    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Which yields a string (from listItem.OuterXML):

```
<rs:data ItemCount="896" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset">
[...]
<z:row ows_Title="Do A B AND C" ows_ProjectID="1165;#_INTERNAL" ows__ModerationStatus="0" ows__Level="1" ows_Deliverables="&lt;div&gt;Implementation of blah blah blah" ows_AssignedTo="7;#blah@xyz.com" ows_ID="5" ows_owshiddenversion="29" ows_UniqueId="5;#{DD129C47-C9E0-4962-A516-B8280EB77800}" ows_FSObjType="5;#0" ows_Created="2009-02-27 08:25:28" ows_Category="7 Internal Project" ows_Comment="&lt;div&gt;Changing to Queue of 22 blah can do blah" ows_Priority="4 Low" ows_Status="1 In Queue" ows_Description_x0020_of_x0020_Work="do blah and blah" ows_FileRef="5;#Lists/Work Tick/5_.000" ows_ProjectOwner="7;#blah@xyz.com" ows_MetaInfo="5;#" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" />
[...]
</rs:data>
```

There are roughly 800 lines like this in the returned string. What's the easiest way to parse the data from each line? I'd also like to strip out the HTML if possible since I want to eventually dump this into SQL server using the SQLClient namespace.

Comment: Using SharePoint 2010? Use the Client Object Model instead, it'll be far, far easier when it comes to shuttling the data into your SQL data access layer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would not have been necessary to parse the data if you had not converted it into strings by using `OuterXml`. The parsed data are already present as `XmlNode` objects.

1. Exactly what sort of "parsing" do you then require?
2. Where do you see any HTML? All I see here is XML.
3. If you are using SQL Server 2005 or later, then you can store the data in columns of type "XML".

Comment: @James: thanks, but he already has `XmlNode` instances. I'm merely suggesting that he use them.

Comment: exactly, I was giving you the up vote as you posted it before I had noticed :P